# What is the difference between Flex mx:DateField disabledRanges = "" and selectableRange = ""?

Tags: apache-flex, datefield

I Want a flex date field with particular selectable range only.

I could there are similar properties of mx:DateField to restrict the selectable date range. that are

```
<mx:DateField disabledRanges="{[{rangeEnd: new Date()}]}"/>
```

and

```
<mx:DateField selectableRange="{{rangeStart : new Date()}}" y="100"/>
```

so i would like to know  what is the difference between above two properties and in which case have to use disabledRanges and selectableRange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disabledRanges` allows you to define **multiple** date ranges to exclude from being selected.[[1]](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html#disabledRanges)

`selectableRange` allows you to define a **single** date range to include for selection.[[2]](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html#selectableRange)

The difference is small but powerful, the ability to define multiple exclusions allows much more customisation.

Imagine you wanted to only allow someone to pick a date in this month, that easy with `selectableRange`, but imagine you also wanted to exclude all weekends and national holidays? You can't do that with one inclusive date range, you need multiple exclusions.

Answer (score 0):

This properties are opposite. With `disabledRanges` you could disable some date (dates) from choosing (and other dates will be available to user) and with `selectableRange` you could set date (dates) that only available (and other dates will be disabled for user).

[disabledRanges](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html#disabledRanges)
[selectableRange](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html#selectableRange)